# Return the index of the min value in panda python

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eeRq.png)
I need compose a list where each element is the index of minimum value; so to have a final output like `['cliks','camp','imp']`

my script:

```
import Levenshtein 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dwh = ['camp','clicks','imp']
tmp = ['click','camp','imp']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[dwh])
n = 0
for e in tmp:
    dwh_elmt = e
    list = []
    for i in dwh:
        Similarity = str(Levenshtein.distance(e,i))
        list.insert(2,Similarity)
    df[tmp[n]] = list
    n = n + 1
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.argmin()` to locate the minimal values, then index into the dataframe column or index.

```py
# Take the minimum along each row.
>>> df.columns[np.argmin(df.values, axis=1)].tolist()
['camp', 'click', 'imp']

# Take the minimum along each column.
>>> df.index[np.argmin(df.values, axis=0)].tolist()
['clicks', 'camp', 'imp']
```

Comment: thanks, it works with df.index[np.argmin(df.values, axis=0)].tolist()